# .htaccess redirecting loop when link is file link but file doesnt exist

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this working .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash On 


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1/ [R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/?]+)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/?]*)/([^/?]*)$ $1.php?$1=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/?]*)/([^/?]*)/([^/?]*)$ $1.php?$2=$3
```

Problem is, that if I dont have any file `http://mydomain/myfile.extension` it jumps to an infinite loop of redirecting... Funny thing is I KNOW why is it so, but I dont know how to fix it - I thought about two solutions though:

1) WORKAROUND - I DONT LIKE IT: add "not a '.' (dot)" into the RewriteRule regular expression - however I am not a regexp master so I am not sure how to add it (and still dont crash the current one)

2) BETTER, but HOW ? : to check if the .php file - which redirect would lead to - even exists

Answer (score 0):

Try your rules like this:

```
DirectorySlash On 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

## If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
## If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
## don't do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ $1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?$1=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: 404 Not found to EVERYTHING that is not a file - however also my current url rewrites domain/dir/something stopped working

Comment: I forgget to mention its in a subdirectory so Im guessong the DOCUMENT ROOT causing the problem? ( `RewriteBase /subdir/` )

Comment: just speaking to the "bottle api", will try ASAP